# How to get the selected user data into the dropdown in sugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have 3 users. IC, Team leader and Admin.

I need to get the IC username list into the dropdown.

Comment: Plz share your code here

Comment: I have created a file "logic_hooks.php". I wrote the code in side the page.  ` $query = "I wrote Sql query";
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($query);
while($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result))
{
$id = $id."<option>".$row['last_name']."</option>";
}
echo "<script>  $('#assigned_user_id_advanced').children().remove().end().append('".$id."') </script>";`

Comment: actually the code is working fine.. but I am getting some issues using this method. like I can see error admin studio side. that's why I am looking for another way.

Comment: I dnt know why you are doing things complex. You just need to create new dropdown and the add value into the dropdown and then add that dropdown into your module edit view using studio.

Comment: How we can add the value to dropdown?

Comment: 1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'schooltype_c',
            'studio' => 'visible',
            'label' => 'LBL_SCHOOLTYPE',
          ),

Comment: You can modify the content of dropdown from custom/include/language directory.